# Run a docker hub container on bluemix without crashing (No valid host was found)

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

I am trying to run my first container on ibm bluemix but so far all container I started just crash. To eliminate problems made by the image, I'm using one straight from docker hub.

```
$cf ic cpi ghost ghost
$cf ic run registry.ng.bluemix.net/xxxx/ghost
```

Full Output: https://gist.github.com/jansauer/167727ef3df463d5594b

After running this I get a container id that is not listed on `cf ic ps` and on the dashboard it just says crashed.

I found this in `cf ic inspect`:

```
"Fault": {
    "code": 500,
    "created": "2015-10-20T18:05:21Z",
    "message": "No valid host was found. Exceeded max scheduling attempts 3 for instance 846b0eed-e41d-465c-a050-ecc57e2a9be9. Last exception: [u'Traceback (most recent call last):\\n', u'  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py\", line 2069, in _do"
},
```

Comment: could you please check with `cf ic ps -a`? that would give you status on all containers (not only the ones running)

Comment: also running $ cf ic logs NAME will give you the container logs to see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

there was some issues with containers on 20 oct 2015 ( status on: https://status.ng.bluemix.net/  ) but they seems resolved.

Regards